# Riemann-Hurwitz over non algebraically closed field

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I'm trying to understand where is the failure in Riemann-Hurwitz when the field $k$ is not algraically closed. Taking $f:X\to Y$ separable finite morphism between complete non singular curves. For me Riemann-Hurwitz says that
$$ 2-2g_X=\deg(f)(2-2g_Y)-\deg(R) $$
with $R$ the divisor
$$ R=\sum_P v_P(f^* ds/dt) P$$
where $s\in\mathcal{O}_{Y,f(P)}$ and $t\in\mathcal{O}_{X,P}$ are uniformizers.

I think that the problem is with $v_P(f^* ds/dt)$: it is not well defined in general because in $\Omega_{X/k,P}$ the element $dt$ is not a basis in general, because it is true if the residu field in $P$ is $k$ ie $P$ is a rationnal point.

So I'm seeking for a example in a $\Omega_{X/k,P}$ where $gdt=0$ and $g\neq 0$.

Idea: $X=\mathbb{A}^1_\mathbb{Q}=\text{Spec}(\mathbb{Q}[x])$, $P$ the point associated with the ideal $(x^2+1)$ (it is not rationnal). Here $\mathcal{O}_{X,P}=\mathbb{Q}[x]_{(x^1+1)}$ has uniformizer $t=x^2+1$. Problem: I can't find $g\in\mathcal{O}_{X,P}$ with $gdt=0$.

Comment: You might find Richard D. James' comment [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3797975/calculating-the-genus-of-a-curve-over-mathbb-q#comment7825085_3797975) helpful. The issue is really that you need to weight your sum by the degree of the residue field. (You also have a couple typos: "finit" instead of "finite", and whatever "Pb" is [presumably not lead?].)

Comment: @KReiser Thanks! The comment you told about deals with the tame ramification where wee can use the formula $e_P-1$. But with wild ramification I guess that we must use the generalization $v_P(df/dt)$?

Comment: $dt$ *is* still a basis. After all, by high school calculus we have $dt=2x\,dx$ and $2x$ is invertible in $\mathcal{O}_{X,P}$. By the way, your version of Riemann-Hurwitz is missing the $\deg f$ factor on the right (or rather the extension degree of the function fields).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Ok my example seems not going in the failure! But in general there is a problem if $P$ is not rationnal: Theorem II.8.8 in Hartshorne doesn't apply to prove that $\Omega_{\mathcal{O}_{X,P}/k}$ is free because here $k$ is not the residu field. There is a problem but I can't exhibe concret problematic example... Maybe there is no problem and with algebraic closness it is more easy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "failure" of Riemann-Hurwitz in the case when the base field isn't algebraically closed case can be fixed by counting degrees appropriately. Your statement that  $$2g_X-2 = \deg(f)(2g_Y-2) + \deg(R)$$ (where $X\to Y$ is a separable morphism of smooth proper curves over a base field $k$) is true no matter the base field. The problem is that you need to be more careful in your calculation of $\deg R$, because it's not just $\sum_P v_P(f^*ds/dt)$.

Write $R=\sum d_ip_i$. The degree of $R$ is defined to be $\dim_k \Gamma(R,\mathcal{O}_{R})$, which is equal to $\sum_{i} \dim_k \mathcal{O}_{R,p_i}$. When $k$ is algebraically closed, $\dim_k\mathcal{O}_{R,p_i}$ is just $d_i=v_{p_i}(f^*ds/dt)$, but if $k$ is not algebraically closed, it's $d_i \dim_k k(x_i)$. From here, one can make the standard calculation that $d_i = e_{p_i}-1$ and the formula becomes $$2g_X-2 = \deg(f)(2g_Y-2)+\sum [k(p_i):k](e_{p_i}-1).$$

If you're interested in further reading, I like [Stacks' treatment](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0C1B), and Richard D. James' comment [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3797975/calculating-the-genus-of-a-curve-over-mathbb-q) may be helpful, where he recommends Rosen's *Number Theory in Function Fields* (I don't have a copy myself, so I can't vouch for it).

Comment: +1 of course. I just want to add that in positive characteristic we may have wild ramification when $d_i>e_{p_i}-1$. The simplest to describe example (I think) is when $X=Y$ is the projeective line over $\Bbb{F}_2$, and $f$ is given by the relation $x=y^2+y$ over the affine charts. At the point of infinity $P_\infty, x=\infty$ we have $e=d=2$. More on [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramification_group). The different exponent can really balloon, when there are several non-trivial higher order ramification groups.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thank you for the instructive example of wild ramification! Usually I enjoy things that are a bit out of the ordinary like that, but I haven't had cause to think too hard on wild ramification in a while and I'm grateful for someone more familiar with the matter saying a few words.

Comment: Thanks for the kind words. I have no doubt that you know AG much better than I do. But, one aspect I have had a reason to familiarize myself is [curves over finite fields](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540768777). In the late 90s I used the $L$-functions related to simple towers of Artin-Schreier extensions (cyclic Galois group) because they popped out in a coding theoretical setting. I have the impression that higher ramification groups are also dealt with regularly in algebraic number theory. So that game is played more on the arithmetic side, I guess :-)

Comment: Thanks! I guess that in the non algebraically closed case one can use $\text{length}(\Omega_{X/Y,P})\times[k(P):k]$ in place of $v_P(df/dt)$. I'd like to have a concret example where $df/dt$ is badly defined...

Comment: @Macadam Length over $k$ is dimension over $k$, so your proposed formula in that last comment isn't quite right (the post's is). And "badly defined" doesn't really make sense.

Comment: @KReiser I fear that the story about $df/dt$ (ie $f^*ds/dt$) will stay obscure for me... to have a sense we must have a $g\in\mathcal{O}_{X/k,P}$ unique with $f^*ds=gdt$ ie I must have $dt$ is a basis in $\Omega_{X/k,P}$. But I don't know if it's true when $P$ is not rationnal. That's what I mean by "badly defined". But as ever there's must be something obvious that I don't see...

Comment: @Macadam $dt$ is certainly a basis: this follows from the structure of a regular local ring of dimension one and how differentials work. If things are still unclear, I think you'd be better served asking another question and getting really specific about what your issue is.

Comment: All is clear: Hartshorne make a assumption that is not necessary. In Liu VI.2.2 is stated that $\Omega_{X/k,x}$ is free of dimension $\dim_x X$ (the infimum of dimension of $\dim U$ for $U\ni x$) iff $X$ is smooth. There is no assumption on $x$ ($X$ must be an algebraic variety over $k$). He goes through $X_{\overline{k}}$.